# Connect To Server not working in UBUNTU

Tags: networking, server, samba

I'm using **UBUNTU 16.04** system. My server is also **UBUNTU**. Initially in my LAN I was able to connect to the server perfectly fine using the **Connect To Server** feature.

All of a sudden Connect To Server stopped working. It wouldn't allow me to connect to the server from my system. I tried re-installing and re-configuring **Samba**, but still it wouldn't work.

It keeps giving me errors as shown in below screenshots.

I tried with `smb://, ftp://, sftp://`, but they all give same result as in below screenshots.

I also tried with the IP Address something like `smb://192.168.0.20/`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like your DNS isn't working as you're used to it anymore. Just use the IP for now. You can also check it with `nslookup ubuntu` if it doesn't return anything you know it's not working. nslookup is available in the package `dns-utils` so you might want to install that first.

Comment: Even with the IP Address I get same error. Package dns-utils wasn't available for install with sudo apt-get install dns-utils

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server and the client can connect to each other, if not the error would be different. This must be happening because of an update of Samba in the server, or (more rare) an update of Nautilus in the client. Also, it's possible that the settings of the server were changed (by another program). Try *purging* Samba (using Synaptic, for example, it's important that all Samba conf files be deleted, so /etc/samba should be empty), reinstall it, and disable encryption / passwords. If the client connects, try enabling them. If it stops connecting, compare the protocols / encryption systems used. Make sure the latest versions of Samba and Nautilus are installed.

Comment: Tried that and still facing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command

sudo apt --reinstall install nautilus

sudo apt-get install --reinstall gvfs-backends -y

nautilus smb://IPADDRESS